# How to generate a new RDD from another RDD according to specific logic

Tags: apache-spark

I am a freshman to Spark. I have a problem, but I don't know how to solve it. My data in RDD is as follows:

```
(1,{A,B,C,D})
(2,{E,F,G})
......
```

I know RDDs are immutable, but, I want to transform my RDD into a new RDD that looks like this:

```
11 A,B
12 B,C
13 C,D
21 E,F
22 F,G
......
```

How can I generate a new key and extract adjacent elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your collection is something similar to a `List`, you could do something like:

```
val rdd2 = rdd1.flatMap { case (key, values) => 
  for (value <- values.sliding(2).zipWithIndex) 
    yield (key.toString + value._2, value._1) 
}
```

What we are doing here is iterating through the values in your list, applying a sliding window of size 2 on the elements, zipping the elements with an integer index, and finally outputting a list of tuples keyed by the original index appended with the list indices (whose values are the slid elements). We also use a flatMap here in order to flatten the results into their own records.

When run in spark-shell, I'm seeing the following output on your example:

```
scala> val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Array((1,List("A","B","C","D")), (2,List("E","F","G"))))
rdd1: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, List[String])] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:21

scala> val rdd2 = rdd1.flatMap { case (key, values) => for (value <- values.sliding(2).zipWithIndex) yield (key.toString + value._2, value._1) }
rdd2: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Seq[String])] = MapPartitionsRDD[1] at flatMap at <console>:23

scala> rdd2.foreach(println)
...
(10,List(A, B))
(11,List(B, C))
(12,List(C, D))
(20,List(E, F))
(21,List(F, G))
```

The one note with this is that the output key (e.g. `10`, `11`) will have 3 digits if you have 11 or more elements. For example, for the input key `1`, you will have an output key `110` on the 11th element. Not sure if that fits your use case, but it seemed like a reasonable extension of your request. Based off your output key scheme, I would actually suggest something different (like maybe adding a hyphen between the key and element?). This will prevent collisions later as you'll see `2-10` and `21-0` instead of `210` for both keys.

Comment: I got it.Thanks very much.You solve my problem perfectly

Comment: @SN.JS please mark the question as answered (click on the check mark to the left of this answer).